# URI::BadURIError - relative URI: /third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec in pod install when upgrading react-native from 0.69.10 to 0.70

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

`In 0.69.10, pod install and IOS build were working fine, but as soon as I upgraded to 0.70, pod install started giving me errors. (Details to follow).

I tried `pod repo update` and `pod deintegrate`, but the error remained the same.

## `pod install`

pod install
RNFBAnalytics: Using default Firebase/Analytics with Ad Ids. May require App Tracking Transparency. Not allowed for Kids apps.
RNFBAnalytics: You may set variable `$RNFirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport=true` in Podfile to use analytics without ad ids.
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBCrashlytics: [RNFB] Crashlytics Configuration
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `Project`: BVLinearGradient, RNAppleAuthentication, RNBootSplash, RNCAsyncStorage, RNCPicker, RNCPushNotificationIOS, RNDateTimePicker, RNDeviceInfo, RNFBAnalytics, RNFBApp, RNFBCrashlytics, RNFBMessaging, RNFS, RNFastImage, RNGestureHandler, RNI18n, RNImageCropPicker, RNLocalize, RNPermissions, RNReactNativeHapticFeedback, RNSVG, RNShare, RNVectorIcons, ReactNativeART, react-native-ad-manager, react-native-add-calendar-event, react-native-adjust, react-native-background-upload, react-native-blob-util, react-native-camera, react-native-cameraroll, react-native-contacts, react-native-device-brightness, react-native-document-picker, react-native-fbsdk, react-native-get-random-values, react-native-in-app-review, react-native-in-app-utils, react-native-keep-awake, react-native-maps, react-native-netinfo, react-native-pdf, react-native-slider, react-native-twitter-signin, react-native-version-number, react-native-video, react-native-view-shot, react-native-viewpager, react-native-webview, and rn-media-meta
Framework build type is static library
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `DCTAuth` from `https://github.com/danielctull/DCTAuth.git`, commit `0a8091a3fc165fb99a6f70cf15b3aed25252dad9`
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

#### Command

```
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/pod install
```

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

```
  CocoaPods : 1.12.1
        Ruby : ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [arm64-darwin22]
    RubyGems : 3.4.10
        Host : macOS 13.4 (22F66)
      Xcode : 14.3.1 (14E300c)
        Git : git version 2.39.2 (Apple Git-143)
Ruby lib dir : /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

#### Podfile

```rb
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'Project' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config["reactNativePath"],
    # Consider to apply hermes engine
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )
  # Pods for Project
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'TwitterCore', '3.1.0'
  pod 'TwitterKit', '3.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'DCTAuth', :git => 'https://github.com/danielctull/DCTAuth.git'
  pod 'RSKImageCropper'

  # React Native Maps dependencies
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'

  pod 'react-native-geolocation', path: '../node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation'

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse.podspec"

  target 'ProjectTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      else
        react_native_post_install(installer)
        __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
        installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### Error

```
URI::BadURIError - relative URI: /third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/uri/generic.rb:1500:in `find_proxy'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/open-uri.rb:197:in `block in open_loop'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/open-uri.rb:214:in `block in open_loop'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/open-uri.rb:212:in `catch'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/open-uri.rb:212:in `open_loop'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/open-uri.rb:153:in `open_uri'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/podspec_source.rb:19:in `block in fetch'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:86:in `titled_section'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/podspec_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:997:in `fetch_external_source'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:976:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:975:in `each'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:975:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:974:in `fetch_external_sources'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:118:in `analyze'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.